# Drag Listitem to Gridview column header or Row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have been given a task which has a **listbox** & a **GridView**.
I don't know whether its possible or not but what i want is, when user drags an item from listbox & drops it on gridview's column header, item should get added on gridviews header. Same way user can drop an item on gridview's row.

Screenshot for reference
[image]

I searched a lot but could not find any relevant material. Is it possible in asp.net ? if not then can this be implemented using some other third party tool?

Comment: Please provide more information as to what are you using? Are you using MVC? Which version? or just plain ASP.Net?

Comment: Plain ASP.Net application